# PWM Battery Charger Power Schematic

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am trying to come up with a simple Battery Charger design, which utilizes PWM control. The use of high frequency PWM is to reduce the size of the Transformer that is to be used. Planning to use Transformer to provide the much required Galvanic Isolation between the AC input and the DC Charging output.

Specs of the Transformer are roughly:
Input: 0-220V
Output: 0-18-36-72 (only 1 tapping shown here).
Transformer primary is driven by a PWM power signal at approx 25KHz. This choice of frequency comes from an application note that the MCU manufacturer has provided. PWM generated from a PIC16F, and will be optically coupled to the MOSFET gate.
The values of C and R shown below are only indicative. Battery temperature is monitored separately and fed to the controller. Also, Battery presence etc are taken care of separately. Vsense is carried out during PWM-OFF cycles, while Isense is done during PWM-ON cycles.

I have few important questions:

1. Primary will already have DC, being switched. Do I still need a rectifier on the secondary? A polarity limiting diode shall be present anyways.
2. I plan to switch the primary, with a single MOSFET. What kind of MOSFET should be used and also how to connect it. I have used an N-Channel Enhancement type. Is this correct?
3. Some designs show an output L-C filter, with L in series and C in parallel to the Battery? Do I need something similar? If yes, Why?
4. The smoothening CAP that I have used on the primary side...what is a good approximation for its capacitance value?
5. What other precautions should be kept? I wish to know if there is something important lacking from this power schematic..something that I might have overlooked.

Please Note, I understand that this is by no means the complete schematic. It would be impossible to provide everything here. My basic question is about the feasibility of the power scheme, and if any additions MUST be done for a viable design. Would help a lot if you could point the glaring issues out.

All help/comments etc are highly welcomed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUEHqB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 1. Do you want to charge your battery with AC? 2. You are way over your head here if you need to ask that. Why don’t you start with a 50/60 Hz iron step down transformer and try making a buck battery charger on the secondary in order to learn? 3. How much ripple are you willing to feed your battery? 4. About 0.5 uF per watt output. 5. Don’t play with mains voltage!

Comment: @winny: (3). So my understanding was the Battery will act has a huge capacitor, when it comes to ripple. Will the battery manufacturer specify this ripple value? This is for a regular Sealed Maintenance Free Lead Acid Battery, 12V, 100AH.

Comment: @winny: (4) Ok, so 0.5uF per watt. Thanks, that's a very good data point.
 
Thanks for your answers. We already make Battery Chargers, which use SCRs commutating over line frequency and feeding a regular line frequency transformer. The problem is Transformer size. I wish to draw upto 20A, at 24V and some extra budget. This leads to a Transformer close to 600VA. Transformer size is quite big. Now, if the frequency can be increased, the inductance required will reduce. So I want to use the present scheme. Also, Thanks for the safety advice. We take due care in dealing with mains.

Comment: @winny: (1). Of course, I want to charge my Battery with DC, but in this case, Transformer primary is being fed with switched DC...which moves between 0 and 220*1.414. The transformer secondary will switch between 0 and 18*1.414. Would that constitute AC?

Comment: @winny: (2). Its just that I have not worked with MOSFETs that much. I use SCRs or Triacs more often.

Comment: 2. You have a steep learning curve ahead of you!

Comment: @winny: :) Thanks for the comment. Can you point to the exact problem in using the MOSFET as it is shown in the schematic above? Also, if you could point me to some exact sources of information about use of MOSFETS/IGBTs in the above scenario. I shall start the climb from there :).

Comment: EMI, transformer calculations, loop stability, overcurrent protection, soft start and inrush, safety, filter calculations, isolation, feedback, fault cases, fire and so on.

Comment: @winny : 
(1),(2). EMI - True. I have asked the Transformer designer to look into this and report values to me. (3),(4),(5) - Shall be implemented in the firmware using existing reference code. (6) Safety: Any specific concern? Please note, this is just the broad power schematic. Lot of details are not shown here. (7) Filter- Yes I need help here. (8)  isolation: Transformer provides isolation from mains to the user. MOSFET gate is optically isolated from control electronics. (9) V-feedback and I-feedback are measured at the given points (10), (11) Fault Cases: Please elaborate.

Comment: You underestimate the difference between your existing SCR design and a primary switched converter. 2. No, you report your requirements to him/her from your design values. 6. Plenty! Your assumed split bobbin design from your existing 50/60 Hz design won’t do so you will need to educate yourself about margin tape, layered isolation and interleaved windings.

Comment: @winny: Thanks. I know that I might be not clear about all the differences between a primary switched converter and our existing SCR design.  (2), (6): My transformer manufacturer already is an expert at high-frequency transformers, so I am leaving all the constructional details to them. I have told him the Voltage ratios, secondary max current draw, and approx PWM frequency. What are the other things that I should specify to the Transformer manufacturer?